# nodejs How do I dynamically load resource javascript files

Tags: node.js

I have a resource loader JS file running on a nodejs server. I want to drop in a bunch of resource js files that the resource loader will load into an array on initialization.

```
    // resource loader js file
    var Resources = (function () {

    var resources = {};

    function Resources(){
    ... loading code here

    // example of use after loading
    resources[key].doStuff();
    }
})();
module.exports.Resources = Resources;
```

In the same directory the developer can just drop in new resource.js files as needed.

```
// resource file
var ResourceA = (function () {

function ResourceA(){
... loading code here

// example of use after loading
  ResourceA.prototype.doStuff= function () {
        // do stuff
    };

})();
```

Comment: require('./resource.js') ?

Comment: The developer would have to add a require for each file. Imagine there are 50 of them. I want the developer to just create the files and not have to modify the resource loader file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New and more simple:

**Install**

```
npm install eloader
```

**Usage**

```
const eloader = require('eloader');
const db = require('db');

eloader.add('db', db)
       .add('list', [2,8]
       .run(__dirname + '\\routes\\');
```

**Git**
https://github.com/augustoeliezer/eloader

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if what you want is to load a bunch of modules in a single folder on the server side, I built this little function to do just that.

```
var path = require('path'),
    walk = require('walk');

function findModules(opts,done){
    var walker  = walk.walk(opts.folder, { followLinks: false }),
        modules = [];

    walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
        var current = path.join(root, stat.name),
            extname = path.extname(current);

        if(extname === '.js' && (opts.filter === undefined || opts.filter(current))){
            var module = require(current);
            modules.push(module);
        }

        next();
    });

    walker.on('end', function() {
        done(modules);
    });
}
```

and then, you call it like this:

```
findModules({
    folder: 'path/to/folder',
    filter: undefined // either undefined or a filter function for module names
}, function(modules){
    // continue
});
```

to install **[walk](https://npmjs.org/package/walk)**:

```
npm install walk --save
```

Comment: small addition to your code. var  module = require("./"+current); without this, i m getting an error saying module not found.